# Параметры в методах

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
public class Math {
    private String a;

    void method() {
        this.a = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Вот есть переменная "а", я в нее передаю строку "Hello".
И есть

```
public class Physics {

    void method1() {
        "и здесь мне нужно использовать переменную "а"
     String b = a + "world";
    }
}
```

Как это сделать? Когда создаю объект, получаю Null.

Comment: "оно мне пишет" - кто это "оно"?

Comment: а что пишите в main? Как минимум надо создать экземпляр класса Math тоже ....

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы используете метод `method1` класса `Physics`, то вы, как минимум, создаете через оператор **new** создаете экземпляр указанного класса и обращаетесь к его методу ((!!!) если конечно метод не является статическим).

Соответственно, тоже самое должно касаться и класса `Math` и его метода `method`. Или, как минимум, передать `new Math()` как параметр в метод (если этот экземпляр потом не нужен будет).

Ибо когда вы пишите `String b = a + "world";`, то это значит, что идет попытка обращения к переменной `a` внутри этого самого класса (Physics). А так как её нет, то и ошибка.

```
public class Math {
    private String a;

    void method() {
        a = "Hello";
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
}


public class Physics {

    void method1(Math math) {
        String b = math.getA() + "world";
    //    System.out.print(b);
    }
}
```

метод **main** может при этом выглядеть так:

```
new Physics().method1(new Math());
```

или

```
Math math = new Math();
Physics physX = new Physics();
physX.method1(math);
```

---

Почему мне кажется, что лучше передавать объект, а не создавать его экземпляр непосредственно в методе `method1` ? Потому что могут быть, например, наследники от класса `Math` и вы захотите вызвать **их** реализацию метода `method`, которая будет отличаться от родительского. И при этом не придется постоянно переписывать метод `method1` и писать различные условия на объекты различного типа.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, необходимо провести инициализацию класса `Math`, затем вызвать метод `method`, который установит значение `a`. 
Теперь, получается так, что извне у нас нет доступа к полю `a`, для этого создан метод `get_a()`, который и возвращает `a`

```
public class Math {

    private String a;

    public String get_a() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public void method() {
        this.a = "Hello";
    }
}

public class Physics {

    public void method1() {
        Math a = new Math();
        a.method();
        String b = a.get_a() + "world";
    }
}
```